A "wallet-recovery" or similar tag?
There are a lot of questions about recovering lost bitcoins, frequently due to the user having to re-download the blockchain and not having compleeted it yet, but also with lost passwords, corrupted files etc.
How about using a standard tag for these, such as:

wallet-recovery
data-recovery
recovery (this exists, but has only been used twice)
loss (exists, used 4 times)

Or something else?

Since the answer is nearly always the same no matter the circumstances of the wallet loss, shouldn't these be getting closed as duplicates?
